# How to fetch my data using Next 13.4 (app folder)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fetch-api

I'm trying to fetch data on my strapi backend.
When i fetch data from a standard React project (vite), all is working great :

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchArticles = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(
          `http://localhost:1337/api/articles?populate=PhotoPrincipale`,
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${import.meta.env.VITE_STRAPI_API}`,
            },
          }
        );
        setArticles(response.data.data as IArticle[]);
        setIsLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        let message = "Unknow error";
        if (error instanceof Error) message = error.message;
        reportError({ message });
      }
    };
    fetchArticles();
  }, []);
```

```
async function getArticles() {
  const res = await fetch(
    "http://localhost:1337/api/articles?populate=PhotoPrincipale",
    {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer xxxxxxxxx`,
      },
    }
  );

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch data");
  }
  return res.json();
}
```

There is something I i do wrong ?

I got this issue on my next project :

[image]